# What to do if you cannot see how to improve your downvoted post?

Tags: support, asking-questions, down-votes

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/546758/web-sniffer-http-viewer?noredirect=1) a week or so ago, but seems somehow the question was off topic.

I researched services that could fit the requirements:

1. Web based
2. Access pages via either HTTP or HTTPS
3. Will allow the query to be bookmarked (i.e., Link to repeat query in a GET request)
4. Follows redirects

and couldn't find any.

Thought I asked an [objective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) question, but it seems not.

Problem is, I can seemingly now no longer ask questions due to my 2(!) downvotes on this sub-site, and cannot for the life of me think of any other action apart from deleting the question I still have not had answered.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand why this question wasn't migrated to webapps. It is a very specific question and fits the Q&A concept. It was well formatted and the OP shows some effort before he asks.

Comment: @nixda - Thanks! (P.S nixda.com listed in your profile, seems to be unclaimed currently)... slhck - Correct (Let me reword the question)

Comment: @DanielBeck - Did you get notified of my attempt to put two @'s in (Found it a tad annoying that I couldn't click through the "only one will be notified" prompt, as I just wanted to delimit one response from the other, and thought I understood that the first commenter always gets notified of subsequent ones), or happened to come across this great question ;) Thanks regardless of the reason!

Comment: Moderators get pinged about every new question on MSU. I just happened to view it after you had posted your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was simply off topic for Super User and has now been migrated to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Looking at your previous questions, I don't see a convincing reason to prevent you from posting. You do have two out of nine questions marked as duplicates, now one of them closed and one migrated. However, I don't see terribly low quality questions there.

Note that the question ban is automated and we can't just change this for you. I undeleted [one of your questions](https://superuser.com/questions/478421/windows-xp-picture-and-fax-viewer-duplicate-windows) which currently has one down vote. Maybe you can fix it and clarify it a little, and that'd help you get back on track. Posting good and useful answers also always helps.

If after that you're still unable to post questions on Super User, do let us know.

Comment: Thanks slhck. Should have thought that webapps was probably a better subsite to ask that question on, though I do remember that the closing reason was that it wasn't a good fit for SE (I do notice that Sathya has changed this to being not a good fit for superuser, which had I seen this originally, likely would have seen what others probably meant and deleted + re-created question on, probably, webapps).

Comment: As for those duplicates - That was an annoying introduction to SE. I asked for a screen capture utility to also allow blurring of surrounding areas in a sub-selection of the capture (like in [this](http://img841.imageshack.us/i/delk.png)). However, after becoming more involved in the community, can see that the subject text was ¿probably a reason?, and should have included the differentiating factor between my question, and others (though no-one suggested this to me). Glad that I got the Snagit answer before the second was closed though, as this was _exactly_ the functionality I was after.

Comment: Anyways - Thanks for recognising that I try to put effort into my content on SE; Have transferred the clarification in that question you undeleted (Thanks) of the reason for the question (which I thought was fine in the comments of the question), into the question itself - Please let me know if you think any further changes would be helpful to keep it open/get an answer; and thanks for being open to address future problems like this.